# Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError https://pypi.org/simple/pprint/

Tags: python, linux, pip, kali-linux, pprint

issue in python pip pkg : **pprint**

```
/bug_bounty/HawkScan$ ls
CHANGELOG.md  config.pyc  Dockerfile   __init__.py  README.md  requirements.txt  sites   sublist
config.py     dico.txt    hawkscan.py  modules      report     setup.py          static  tools
```

when i install this github repo we have issue in python pkg.

> Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (2.22.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (19.0.0)
> Collecting pprint
> **Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/pprint/**

how to solve and install this package?

Answer (score 1):

[pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) is included with Python 2.7, I believe there is no need to try and install it from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/). Try removing `pprint` from the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Thanks but  when i try  remove pprint pkg  .it cant be solve issue .